# Find the number of pairs $(x,y)$ of integer numbers (positive or negative) such that $2020x+2022y+1=xy$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I was struggling for *ages* on this question, and even after careful considering I cannot make sense of this with my knowledge of algebra or set theory.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Have you tried to rewrite the equation in a factored form?

Comment: This seems to me a number theory problem, not set theory.

Comment: Where is this question from?

Comment: **Complete the product**, as in the linked dupe.

Comment: thanks for the advice @hardmath, I did spent hours rewrite the equation too. but I couldnt get nowhere.

Comment: Thanks @line student, I corrected.

Comment: hi @player3236., my teacher made this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$xy-2020x-2022y=1$$

$$(x-2022)(y-2020)=1+2020*2022$$

$$2020*2022+1=2021^2=(43*47)^2$$

$$x-2022=\pm(1,43,47,43^2,2021,47^2,2021^2)$$

Then you can just solve for x and y algebraically

Comment: Also, every enumerated number can be $\pm$, e.g. $x - 2022 = -2021 = y - 2020$ gives a solution $(1, -1)$.

Comment: I've made the edit, thanks for the feedback